# Rails 6.1: Webpacker can't find application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

Installing a new application with rails 6.1.4. When running the application I get the following....

From browser:

```
Showing /home/james/ReachTech/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:

Webpacker can't find application.js in /home/james/ReachTech/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:

1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.

Your manifest contains:
{
}
Extracted source (around line #10):
8
9
10
11
12
13
              

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
```

I am wanting to use javascript. Ive restarted the application multiple times. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of `layouts/application.html.erb`. See also docs: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html

Comment: Have you try running `yarn install` so it installs the required yarn packages for webpack to work?

Answer (score -1):

Please run this command

```
yarn install
```